# Where would be an appropriate location in Angular 2+ to keep Jasmine data fixtures?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, fixtures

I have several json responses (from backend) that I use in Jasmine specs, to test component and service functionality.

Recently I figured to move those responses into files in order to share data across multiple specs. However I can't find recommended location to store those files in. I saw an example, where spec fixtures are placed in `assets` folder, however I believe it is a wrong place, since Angular includes `assets` folder into a build.

Is there a recommended location for spec fixtures in Angular structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question is highly opinionated with respect to where to put the JSON files. However, inside your `tsconfig.app.json`, you can put in an `exclude` key that takes an array of directory locations to exclude when building and serving your application.

I would recommend to create a new folder inside your assets folder to store all your JSON responses, and then exclude that folder in your `tsconfig.app.json`

Example:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/assets/test-data"
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I was hoping that there is an actual recommended/documented place for jasmine spec resource.

Comment: No, it's completely up to you where you'd like to put your testing files. Angular is opinionated but not to that level.